# Where are the dependencies to compile Python on windows?

Tags: python, c++, c, windows, compilation

Ever since these opensource developers have made it so the only way to get a compiled binary is to use their MSI installer (rather than a straight zip file), I have been compiling projects like Apache, PHP, etc.

Now in order to compile node.js, it requires Python. So off I went and downloaded the Python source tar-ball (pretty used to this by now), cracked it open in Visual Studio, migrated (from VS2010 to VS2013), and went to build --  missing dependencies.  Now just so we are clear, the only dependencies missing are the headers for some other projects such as openssl, and sqlite.

sqlite was a breeze since their .h files are all that is in their source tarball, so dropped that into '/Include/', and so far seems to be no issues there.

When I went to grab the source tarball for openssl, after locating where the headers are in the file, i went to extract just the headers, and oops....  I am on windows, so virtual links don't work -.- .   These files (according to the build errors) are supposed to be in 'openssl/*' so assuming '/Include/openssl/'.

A brief list of the errors for missing headers/linked dependencies is as follows:

```
Error   68  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'bzlib.h': No such file or directory c:\src\Python-3.4.3\Python-3.4.3\Modules\_bz2module.c   12  1
Error   76  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/evp.h': No such file or directory   c:\src\Python-3.4.3\Python-3.4.3\Modules\_hashopenssl.c 22  1
Error   61  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/rsa.h': No such file or directory   c:\src\Python-3.4.3\Python-3.4.3\Modules\_ssl.c 59  1
Error   58  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory   c:\src\python-3.4.3\python-3.4.3\modules\_sqlite\connection.h   33  1
Error   59  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory   c:\src\python-3.4.3\python-3.4.3\modules\_sqlite\connection.h   33  1
Error   60  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory   c:\src\python-3.4.3\python-3.4.3\modules\_sqlite\connection.h   33  1
Error   62  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory   c:\src\python-3.4.3\python-3.4.3\modules\_sqlite\connection.h   33  1
Error   63  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory   c:\src\python-3.4.3\python-3.4.3\modules\_sqlite\connection.h   33  1
Error   64  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory   c:\src\python-3.4.3\python-3.4.3\modules\_sqlite\connection.h   33  1
Error   65  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory   c:\src\python-3.4.3\python-3.4.3\modules\_sqlite\connection.h   33  1
Error   66  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tcl.h': No such file or directory   c:\src\Python-3.4.3\Python-3.4.3\Modules\_tkinter.c 55  1
Error   67  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tcl.h': No such file or directory   c:\src\Python-3.4.3\Python-3.4.3\Modules\tkappinit.c    16  1
Error   69  error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\externals\bzip2-1.0.6\blocksort.c': No such file or directory c:\src\Python-3.4.3\Python-3.4.3\PCbuild\c1
Error   70  error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\externals\bzip2-1.0.6\bzlib.c': No such file or directory c:\src\Python-3.4.3\Python-3.4.3\PCbuild\c1
Error   71  error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\externals\bzip2-1.0.6\compress.c': No such file or directory  c:\src\Python-3.4.3\Python-3.4.3\PCbuild\c1
Error   72  error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\externals\bzip2-1.0.6\crctable.c': No such file or directory  c:\src\Python-3.4.3\Python-3.4.3\PCbuild\c1
Error   73  error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\externals\bzip2-1.0.6\decompress.c': No such file or directory    c:\src\Python-3.4.3\Python-3.4.3\PCbuild\c1
Error   74  error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\externals\bzip2-1.0.6\huffman.c': No such file or directory   c:\src\Python-3.4.3\Python-3.4.3\PCbuild\c1
Error   75  error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\externals\bzip2-1.0.6\randtable.c': No such file or directory c:\src\Python-3.4.3\Python-3.4.3\PCbuild\c1
Error   2   error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\externals\sqlite-3.8.3.1\sqlite3.c': No such file or directory    c:\src\Python-3.4.3\Python-3.4.3\PCbuild\c1
```

In addition, there are a number of deprecated errors which I am just going to ignore.  I really have an aversion to running these MSI installers as I have traced several and found that rather than giving the user full control of the destination and ALL dependencies, they generally drop litter everywhere (windows system directory, windows directory, it's own sub-directories in windows and/or nested deep in users, in addition to the path the user specifies). I like to keep my 'installs' a bit more compact and organized, and also, I do enjoy 64 bit builds where typically, there is only 32 bit builds when it comes to what you can get pre-built in MSI/exe installers.

(sorry to rant, but I really don't understand why they make multiple binary distributions for various builds of linux and even mac that are just extract and run, yet for windows -- the build only the 32bit and pack it into a crappy MSI)

Second part of rant -- why don't they just put the libs they use in the sources -.- ...  kind of like buying a car and it comes with no wheels or engine - just the body.

In a nutshell, the problem I have is the header libs weren't properly distributed with the source tarballs for Python.  To compile Python, I need Openssl headers which their source tarball only links the headers (look at the path for where the headers for distribution are located), ironically, to compile openssl, it requires python XD --- cyclic redundancy error with this mentality -- almost to the which comes first -- Python (the chicken) or Openssl (the egg).

I am looking for a way to resolve this conundrum, and if anyone could give some insight as to why open-source projects like this piss all over windows distributions, it would be much appreciated.  I am thinking because it is so easy to auto-build/deploy for MSI and they have just been too lazy to change that in their infrastructure to drop a zip of the compiled binaries.  (some actually do release proper 64 bit zipped builds like MySQL)

- [Pyton Source (stable)](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-343/) Gzipped source tarball-
- [Compiling Python](https://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#windows-compiling)
- [sqlite headers](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) sqlite-amalgamation-3081002.zip (1.52 MiB)
- [OpenSSL source](https://www.openssl.org/source/) openssl-1.0.2d.tar.gz
- [Compiling OpenSSL](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) (was trying to find the link to where it said Python was required, but unable to at the moment)

Comment: Think I may have located where they stashed the dependencies. Crossing my fingers and doing an `svn export http://svn.python.org/projects/external/` . Will grab the files by hand (looks like compiling svn.exe is next on my todo list since that too, is MSI installer only now -.- ) ( http://nightlybuilds.tortoisesvn.net/latest/x64/full/ ) -  they removed the 'small' build http://nightlybuilds.tortoisesvn.net/latest/x64/small/ which did have a stand-alone svn.exe

Comment: grrrrrrrr.......  more symlink crap.   just loving this wear & tear on my drives.

Comment: 'nmakehlp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,    -.-

Comment: The build instructions on the GitHub page say you need [Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2710) (e.g. its configure script uses Python 2 syntax). The Visual Studio 2008 build instructions (the only tested and supported Windows build environment for 2.7) are in [PCbuild/readme.txt](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/15c95b7d81dc/PCbuild/readme.txt). Alternatively, [WinPython](http://winpython.github.io) is a portable Python.